# Adding date column for hour wise data

Tags: python, pandas

I have hour wise raw data for a month. I know start date, But I want to create a Dataframe and add date column for each row.
I know I can create date dataframe using

`df = pd.date_range('25/08/2020', periods = 10, freq ='D')`

But I want it to correspond to this hour wise data.
Time is in 24 hour format. How will I be able to achieve this.
Attaching image of data

[image]

**Edit 1:**
Start time is not fixed. As the data is in 24 hour format, Any row after 23:59 to be treated as next day.
Here is the expected output.

```
| Date       | Time  |       
|------------|-------|       
| 01/01/2020 | 23:45 |       
| 02/01/2020 | 00:01 |       
| 02/01/2020 | 22:45 |       
| 03/01/2020 | 01:30 |
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have any information on which times corresponds to which day of the month? Or does your Series start at 0:00:00 on the first day of the month?

Comment: _please_ add your data as text and not an image, with your expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a dataframe with time strings:

```
    Time         
1  23:45         
2  00:01         
3  22:45         
4  01:30
```

What we need to measure is the change in days, and then applying a rolling cumulative sum.

Let's cast this to a datetime object and measure a `diff()` based on the row above:

```
days = (pd.to_datetime(df['Time'],format='%H:%M')
                                 .diff() / np.timedelta64(1,'D')).lt(0).astype(int).cumsum() 
print(days)
1    0
2    1
3    1
4    2
Name: Time, dtype: int32
```

Now, we just need to increment the days onto your start date, to do this we need to cast the `Days` series into a timedelta object specifying the unit as days. `D`

```
df['Date'] = pd.Timestamp('01 Jan 2020') +  pd.to_timedelta(days,unit='D')

        Date   Time         
1 2020-01-01  23:45         
2 2020-01-02  00:01         
3 2020-01-02  22:45         
4 2020-01-03  01:30
```